# Continue fscanf after using it

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to build a matrix from a text file after the number of columns and rows +1 are given in the text file. The matrix is separated by commas and are double values.

ex

4

3

1.32,4.32,5.6764,5.6545,54.6766

2.32,2.43,4.765,5.453,432.12

3.423,5.34,7.4534,5.3,7.321

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *train;

    train = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    int abutes,examples;
    fscanf(train," %d %d",&abutes,&examples);  /*scan in number of examples and attributes*/
    printf("%d", abutes);
    printf("%d", examples);

    /*make array using malloc*/

    double ** trainA = NULL;
    int i=0;
    int abuteswp;
    int abuteswp1;
    int j=0;
    abuteswp=abutes+1;

    abuteswp1=abutes+2;
    trainA = malloc( examples * sizeof(double *));

    for(i = 0; i < examples; i++)
    {
        trainA[i] = malloc( abuteswp1 * sizeof(double));
    }
    for(i = 0; i <examples; i++)
    {
        trainA[i] = malloc( examples * sizeof(double));
    }
    for (j = 1; j < examples; j++){
        // read the first value into the 0-th element of the j-th row
        fscanf(train, " %lf", &trainA[j][0]);

        // read remaining values, testing for a comma
        // before each value and discarding it
        for (i = 2; i < abuteswp+1; i++){
            fscanf(train, ",%lf", &trainA[j][i]);
        }
    }

    int p;
    /*add in 1s to matrix*/
    for (p=0;p<examples;p++) {
        trainA[p][0]=1;
    }

    for (j=0;j<examples;j++) {
        for ( i=0; i <abuteswp1; i++) {
            printf("%lf", trainA[j][i]);
        }
    }

    free(trainA);
    return 0;
}
```

scans until 4th row 2nd column why does it stop?

Comment: Two points about `printf("%lf     ", trainA[j][i]);` a) the format spec for `double` is `%f` (but not in `scanf`) and b) the containing loop is incorrect since `for ( i=1; i <abuteswp+1; i++)` will break the array `double trainA[examples][abuteswp]`, it should be `for ( i=0; i <abuteswp; i++)`

Comment: I know this isn't the final matrix as I have to add a row of ones to the first column.

Comment: I've simplified so it looks like a normal matrix for explanation

Comment: Please see the `scanf()` description, e.g. at [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) for an explanation of `"%[^charset]"` format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

The second one doesn't work as you expect because it doesn't contain a field conversion specifier.

In short: add a percent sign.

In details: as described at [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), when `scanf()` (same for `fscanf()` etc.) encounters a **non-whitespace character, except format specifier (which starts with % sign)** it compares the incoming character of the input to that character in the format string; if they match, the input character is discarded and scanning continues with a next character, otherwise `scanf()` fails and returns.

So you need to read the first number 'as is' but you need to discard a comma character before reading each of the remaining numbers in the same row:

```
    for (j = 0; j < examples; j++){
        // read the first value into the 0-th element of the j-th row
        fscanf(train, "%lf", &trainA[j][0]);

        // read remaining values, testing for a comma
        // before each value and discarding it
        for (i = 1; i < abuteswp; i++){
            fscanf(train, ",%lf", &trainA[j][i]);
        }
    }
```

You may also want to check the return value from `fscanf()` to make sure the input file actually contained correct amount of data and in expected format

Comment: Thanks I think as I was trying to fix my error I managed to delete the percent sign. When i do put the percent sign I just get the error expects argument of type char but argument 3 has type double. why is it expecting a char?

Comment: @Devs1575 Please see the expanded answer above.

Comment: I used that and scanning looks like its working as I'm no longer getting that error